# Using Google Apps Script to check if a website updates

Tags: video, web, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, pull

I'm trying to write a google apps script application that continuously saves recorded Xbox game clips to google drive.

### Solution

Using the [Xbox API](https://xboxapi.com/) you can grab the data directly from them. 
Specifically game clips using

```
/v2/{xuid}/game-clips
```

Xbox API however requires authentication and google apps script doesn't directly support that so here is a recommended third party solution.

[OAuth1 for apps script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth1)

To get this project done here are other helpful links I used:

[Add Url file to drive - https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/8134679](https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/8134679)

[External APIs for apps script - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)

[Xbox API - https://xboxapi.com/documentation](https://xboxapi.com/documentation)

### Previous Question

I've messed around with "UrlFetchApp.fetch" to check and find content on a webpage.

Here is an example: [Google Apps Script to grab data from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028614/google-apps-script-to-grab-data-from-webpage)

```
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://oldschool.runescape.com/slu').getContentText();
var number = page.match(/There are currently ([0-9,]+)/)[1];
```

This is great for getting existing data, but in order for this app to work as designed I want it to continuously check for new content. Even if it checks every so often, it needs to look at the website and see a difference or change in order to run.

**My Question:
How can I get google apps script to check a website content for a change?**

What I'm trying to do:

I want to use, [XboxClips.com](http://xboxclips.com) on a specific user and check for when a new clip is added. That way from there I can download it and add it to google drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scraping a website for content is considered unethical. However the site you've referenced leverages a publicly available rest api called the [XBox One API](https://xboxapi.com/).

Sign up for the service to get access to the api. Then you can poll the requisite endpoints using a time-based trigger (for more info on time-based triggers check the [apps script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)).

Comment: I don't think it's unethical.